# Passing single paramter to controller inside route group laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently working on a quite the large website in laravel 5.2 and i want to store the choice of languages inside a route middleware, this works as expected. But when i set a route controller inside the group the controller gets two variables instead of one. The language and the second variable to the controller as shown under. 
Is there any way to only pass one variable to the controller instead of two?

```
//Routing: 
Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}',  'middleware' => ['info']], function()
{

    Route::get("template/{template}", 'TemplateController@getTemplate');
}


//Example method in controller: 
public function getTemplate($language, $template)
{

    return response($template);
}

//What i want in the controller.  
public function getTemplate($template)
{

    return response($template);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging into the `Illuminate\Routing\Route` class:

```
/**
 * Unset a parameter on the route if it is set.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @return void
 */
public function forgetParameter($name)
```

You can use `forgetParameter` to forget a parameter. You could call this from your language middleware.

```
$request->route()->forgetParameter('language');
```

Once forgotten the parameter won't be passed to the controller method, leaving only your template param to be passed.